# How to extract C code from the HTML using scrapy?

Tags: python, c, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using scrapy using anaconda command line, to extract C code from the github site (HTML). It is in the form of

[image]
I need to extract the data same as in left side of image.

I used XPATH to extract the required code

```
import scrapy


class TestCCodeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_c_code'
    allowed_domains = ['github.com']
    start_urls = ['http://github.com/gouravthakur39/beginners-C-program-examples/blob/master/AllTempScalesConv.c/']
    
    custom_settings={'FEED_URI': "test_c.csv",
                       'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
    
    def parse(self, response):

        print("processing:" +response.url)
        notation =  response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td[@class='blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line']/text()").extract()
        text_td =  response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td[@class='blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line']/span/text()").extract()

        row_data=zip(notation, text_id)
        
        for i in row_data:
            
            scrapped_info = {
                
                'notation': row_data[0],
                'text': row_data[1],
                }

            

            yield scrapped_info
```

When I run the individually XPATHs it gives result right like

```
response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td[@class='blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line']/text()").extract()
```

and It gives
[image]

While for other extraction

```
response.xpath("//table[@class='highlight tab-size js-file-line-container']/tr/td[@class='blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line']/span/text()").extract()
```

[image]
Anybody Can guide me, how can I access the complete code from HTML without facing any distortion in C code.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using two ways -

A. Use this xpath instead - `normalize-space(//div[@itemprop='text'])`. This gave me the desired result.

B. Crawl following URL instead -
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gouravthakur39/beginners-C-program-examples/master/AllTempScalesConv.c/. Haven't checked the xpath for this though.

Hope this answers!

Comment: @muhammad-umar Let us know if this helped!

Comment: Thanks so much for you reply. but I am selecting the single line, although the class name is same for all rows.`
``In [13]: response.xpath("normalize-space(//td[@class='blob-code blob-code-inner js-file-line'])").extract()
Out[13]: ['#include <stdio.h>']
```